# AppleScript to save web content as PDF throws error : “Can't set window "Save" to …”

Tags: applescript

I am trying to save the web content of a URL I have opened in Safari as PDF. I was able to successfully achieve it through Automator but I want an AppleScript to do this.

Here is the script I am trying to run, which is throwing me an error:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t set window \"Save\" to \"~/Desktop/Reports/\"." number -10006 from window "Save"
```

Steps I did:

1. created a shortcut for Save as PDF…
2. opened Safari that has some web content
3. run the following script:

   ```
   set destination_folder to "/Users/swatt/Desktop/Reports"
   tell application "System Events"
       keystroke "p" using {command down} -- activate print menu item
       delay myDelay
       keystroke "p" using {command down, option down, control down} -- to select the Save as PDF… option
       keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down} -- to select the folder location

       set value of text field 1 of sheet of window "Save" to destination_folder

       -- Now click the Go button
       click button "Go" of sheet of window "Save"
       delay myDelay

       -- Now that we are in our desired folder, set the file name and save
       set value of text field 1 of window "Save" to "TestResults.pdf"

       --click button "Save" of window "Save"
       click button "Go"
   end tell
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts work on the frontmost application, but for the UI elements (**window**, **text field**, ...), you must specify the process

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        keystroke "p" using {command down} -- activate print menu item
        --  other lines
        --
    end tell
end tell
```